# Xeon Phi repeated BIOS beeps

Tags: motherboard, xeon

I have a simple H61 chipset motherboard with Pentium G630. I have enabled Above 4G decoding in the BIOS. The BIOS beeps around 34 beeps and there is no video. I have also tried with setting to Integrated Graphics. The motherboard uses AMI BIOS.

Comment: AMI BIOS does not have a 34 beeps error code, so this is a continuous beep. Try to undo what you did for Above 4G decoding. If this doesn't help, try to disconnect parts until the beep codes change. As this is a very old computer, the repair-shop will be too costly and perhaps for nothing.

Comment: The motherboard does POST and video is working without the card. I just read the MPSS  guide, it says that the processor should have Turbo boost technology. So, Pentium G630 doesnt come with Turbo boost. guess I have to check with core i5

Comment: I think the Turbo Boost is optional, not sure. http://registrationcenter.intel.com/irc_nas/15904/mpss_users_guide.pdf

Comment: It was heating issue at startup. Somehow the card stayed cool. The motherboard POSTs and boots. When I tried to check if the card is there, the lspci didnt give any results for Co-processor

Comment: If this is a hardware problem, we can't help much.

Comment: Unfortunately the power connector was loose and it is now connected properly. And we are back with same beeps.

Comment: Card worked on 6th gen motherboard with Above 4G decoding set to Enabled.